# problem in opening app due to virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine

I have an app which is provided by a coaching institute which I use to watch video lecture provided by them(which are encrypted and only run by the app). but recently i am having a problem while opening the app when ever I open it, it shows "Sorry this app can not under a virtual machine". and I have not  installed any virtual machine app. Please help how can I make it right.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a not a programming question. Stackoverflow is meant for questions that related to codes and software programming languages

Comment: I am sorry I will delete it

Comment: But where else can I ask this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to search for relevant sites from here:
https://stackexchange.com/sites